# SQL server 2005 - query aribitrary time interval in date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a DateTime column. I want to extract all records, lets say, from 8:30 to 16:15 within a certain date range. My problem is that I need to compare hour and minute as a single time value. I can test the DATEPART for Greater or Less than some hours value, but if I then do that for minutes my query will fail if the later-in-the-day time has a smaller minutes value.

I have looked at INTERVAL, BETWEEN, DATEPART, DATEDIFF etc, but don't see quite how to to this without a "TimeOfDay" value that I can use across records of different dates.

I have tried subtracting the year, month and day parts of the date so that I can compare just the time of day, but when attmpting to subract, say, the year part of a date I get an overlfow error:

This part works:

```
select - cast( DATEPART(YEAR, CallTime) as integer) from history
```

This fails:

```
select DATEADD(YEAR, - cast( DATEPART(YEAR, CallTime) as integer), CallTime) 
from history where calltime is not null
```

I have also tried casting the hours and minutes parts to chars, concatenating them and comparing to my target range, but this also fails.

I believe newer versions of SQL server may have a function to deal with this situation, but that's not available to me.

I hope and imagine there is a simple, obvious solution to this, but it's eluding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a "MinuteOfDay" function that calculates how many minutes have passed in the day based on a datetime.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[MinuteOfDay] 
(
    @dt datetime
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (datepart(hh,@dt)*60) + datepart(mi,@dt) 
END
```

then use the result of that function to filter.

```
select * 
from MyTable t 
where dbo.MinuteOfDay(t.SomeDateTimeColumn) between dbo.MinuteOfDay('1900-1-1 08:30:00') and dbo.MinuteOfDay('1900-1-1 16:15:00')
```

Comment: Thank you eoldre! This does the trick nicely. The half brick in the bicycle path of my progress was that I was stuck on trying to do everything within the query itself, rather than creating a function.

Answer (score 0):

give this a shot:

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime  datetime
       ,@EndDateTime    datetime

--date range is ALL of January 1st up to & including 31st
SELECT @StartDateTime='2011/01/01'
      ,@EndDateTime='2011/01/31'

SELECT
    *
    FROM TableName  t
    WHERE 
        t.ColumnDate>=@StartDateTime AND t.ColumnDate<@EndDateTime+1 --date range
        AND LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(19),t.ColumnDate(),120),8),5)>='08:30' --time range start
        AND LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(char(19),t.ColumnDate(),120),8),5)<='16:15' --time range end
```

if you have an index on t.ColumnDate, this should be able to take advantage of it.

the "date range" part of the WHERE throws away rows that are not within the intended date range.  The "time range start" part of the WHERE throws away rows that are to early in time and the "time range end" throws away rows that are to late.

Answer (score 0):

DATETIME values can be cast as FLOAT.  Actually, a DATETIME is stored as a FLOAT.

The whole part of the FLOAT is the days since '12/31/1899' (or something close).  The fractional part is the number of hours divided by 24.  So 0.5 = 12 Noon.

08:30 is 0.3541666667

16:15 is 0.6770833333

SELECT CAST(CAST('2011-03-25 08:30:00' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) = 40625.3541666667

SELECT CAST(CAST('2011-03-25 16:15:00' AS DATETIME) AS FLOAT) = 40625.6770833333

So you could write

SELECT * FROM users WHERE hire_date < 40625.3541666667

Using a DATETIME as FLOAT you can use whichever mathematical functions work best for your query.

Comment: `DATETIME` is not stored as a float. It is stored as 2 integers with one being the date, and the other the time.  I see absolutely no point in using float here. All it can possibly add is incorrect results due to floating point rounding issues.

Comment: BTW: To see this you can use `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND,CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST(GETDATE() as binary(8)),5,4) AS INT)/300.00,0)`